# How can I update to the latest bash in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: bash

I am using `mcfly` (https://github.com/cantino/mcfly). There is a known bug in bash version 5.1 (https://github.com/cantino/mcfly/issues/240, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2022-03/msg00019.html), which should have been fixed in later versions of bash. My version of bash in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is `5.1.16(1)-release`.

Is there a way to update bash to a later version (with the fix) or do I need to wait for Ubuntu to incorporate it in some later patch/version?

Comment: Ubuntu repositories usually do not have the latest packages. https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software  It is unclear why you can't update or what you've tried, but if that is the case, you need to file a bug report and then wait.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I haven't tried anything yet, because I couldn't find a way to do it. That's why I'm asking. Can I add a non-stable repo to update bash from? If so, which one?

Comment: I'd think it be easier to use zsh instead (and it seems this thing supports zsh). How did you install this? Using Linuxbrew? If so, maybe try installing bash with Linuxbrew and using it as your shell (change with `chsh`). Then you can leave the system bash untouched.

Comment: I don't remember now, probably with Homebrew. I will need to test these solutions on another installation, this is my work laptop, don't want to mess things up. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to mess things up, definitely don't change the system bash

Comment: I couldn't find a related article for Ubuntu, but here they say it's safe on OS X: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/is-it-safe-to-upgrade-bash-via-homebrew
Doesn't seem to affect the system bash.